# i am unable to run my flutter application in real device as well as emulator in android studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

**Even if physical device is connected and its showing in device manager,its not showing in run configuration and am unable to run my application.**

this is the result of flutter doctor -v

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1706], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.0.1 at C:\src\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision fb57da5f94 (4 weeks ago), 2022-05-19 15:50:29 -0700
    • Engine revision caaafc5604
    • Dart version 2.17.1
    • DevTools version 2.12.2

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 16.11.15)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools
    • Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 version 16.11.32510.428
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0

[√] VS Code (version 1.62.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\KINGDOMSHOWROOM\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension can be installed from:
       https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1706]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 102.0.5005.63
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 102.0.1245.33

[√] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

**I tried invalidating cache and restarting android studio, swaping cable. but still cant run.**

Answer (score 0):

When you connect a real device, turn on the USB debugging on your real device.

Answer (score 0):

In the previous project i had did `flutter config --no-enable-android` because i needed only windows.. so the issue solved by `flutter config --enable-android`